# Summing multiple loss in keras

Tags: keras

I am training a model that has two outputs, I get losses for both outputs, `out_1_loss` and `out_2_loss` that do not add up to the `loss` that is also displayed. Why is this happening ?

my model:

```
my_mdl = Model(Input_,[out_1,out_2])
```

and uses two losses:

```
my_mdl.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
               loss = {'out_1': 'binary_crossentropy',
                       'out_2': 'mse'})
```

When I run fit on the model:

```
history = my_mdl.fit(train_x, {'out_1': train_y, 'out_2': train_x},
                     epochs=100,
                     batch_size=256,
                     validation_data=(val_x, {'out_1': val_y, 'out_2': val_x}))
```

This is the keras log from `fit`:
[image]

**Answer:**

I had a `kernel_regularizer` in some of my dense layers which were adding a loss term to the the total loss

Comment: Hey, can you show some logs line in your learning phase?

Comment: @sslloo I just did

Comment: I don't know if you are looking for `loss` or `metric` in your case, It works with different metrics for sure

Comment: @sslloo So I am referring to loss e.g. 27.99 in epoch 1 which is not = out_1_loss + out_2_loss. I deliberately kept out the metrics for this question to prevent confusion

Comment: Try to add `lossWeights = {"out_1": 1.0, "out_2": 1.0}` and than `my_mdl.compile(...,loss_weights=lossWeights)`.

Comment: @kruxx i did that and gives me same result

Comment: Actually I even did something else, I tried to check if this also occurs with a model that uses 1 loss, and it seems that also the loss gives a different value there as well. I tested that adding an 'mse' metric, which should be the value of the loss. To my surprise the loss value was largely different.

Comment: @kruxx am sorry I cannot share the code

Comment: Can you add information about keras and backend version?

Comment: I use keras 2.2.2 with Tensorflow backend, tensorflow 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

According to information provided by you, I created your use case as follows (let me know if I have assumed something wrong):

```
print('Keras version: ', keras.__version__)
print('Backend TF version: ', tf.__version__)

# Sample model
Input_ = Input(shape=(10,))
h1 = Dense(5)(Input_)
out_1 = Dense(5,name='out_1')(h1)
out_2 = Dense(10,name='out_2')(h1)
my_mdl = Model(Input_,[out_1,out_2])
print(my_mdl.summary())

my_mdl.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
               loss = {'out_1': 'binary_crossentropy',
                       'out_2': 'mse'})

#Data
train_x = np.random.rand(2560,10)
train_y = np.random.rand(2560,5)

val_x = np.random.rand(100,10)
val_y = np.random.rand(100,5)

#Training
history = my_mdl.fit(train_x, {'out_1': train_y, 'out_2': train_x},
                     epochs=5,
                     batch_size=256,
                     validation_data=(val_x, {'out_1': val_y, 'out_2': val_x}))
```

**Output**

```
Keras version:  2.2.2
Backend TF version:  1.8.0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 10)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 5)            55          input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out_1 (Dense)                   (None, 5)            30          dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
out_2 (Dense)                   (None, 10)           60          dense_1[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 145
Trainable params: 145
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 2560 samples, validate on 100 samples
Epoch 1/5
2560/2560 [==============================] - 0s 81us/step - loss: 6.2931 - out_1_loss: 5.8374 - out_2_loss: 0.4558 - val_loss: 5.9223 - val_out_1_loss: 5.4799 - val_out_2_loss: 0.4424
Epoch 2/5
2560/2560 [==============================] - 0s 7us/step - loss: 6.1148 - out_1_loss: 5.7093 - out_2_loss: 0.4055 - val_loss: 5.7849 - val_out_1_loss: 5.3890 - val_out_2_loss: 0.3959
Epoch 3/5
2560/2560 [==============================] - 0s 7us/step - loss: 5.9467 - out_1_loss: 5.5803 - out_2_loss: 0.3663 - val_loss: 5.6516 - val_out_1_loss: 5.2935 - val_out_2_loss: 0.3581
Epoch 4/5
2560/2560 [==============================] - 0s 7us/step - loss: 5.8020 - out_1_loss: 5.4687 - out_2_loss: 0.3333 - val_loss: 5.5436 - val_out_1_loss: 5.2183 - val_out_2_loss: 0.3253
Epoch 5/5
2560/2560 [==============================] - 0s 13us/step - loss: 5.6643 - out_1_loss: 5.3595 - out_2_loss: 0.3048 - val_loss: 5.4206 - val_out_1_loss: 5.1241 - val_out_2_loss: 0.2964
```

And final loss is sum of `out_1_loss` and `out_2_loss`.

Comment: Thank you for doing this, I just reran this and gives me the correct loss as the addition of both losses (same as your output). I am now re investigating the network...

Comment: I had a kernel_regularizer which was causing this.... I just added that to the question